# Regular expression to parse Table and Select from HTML

Tags: html, regex

I know Regular Expression is not right track to do this parsing job but it is recommended from my side.

If i have a HTML this below. I want to parse all the select info from html table. For this i have used

```
<table id='options_table'>\s*?(.+)?\s*?</table>
```

But this above giving me null result.

and then to parse all select returned from above regex i will use

```
<SELECT.*?>(.*?)<\/SELECT>
```

But above both getting null result.

What should be the regex for Table and Select (from parsed table html) ?

**HTML Part**

```
<table id='options_table'>
    <tr><td colspan=3><font size="3" class="colors_productname">
    <i><b>Color</b></i>
    </font>
    <br /><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td><img class="vCSS_img_line_group_features" src="/v/vspfiles/templates/192/images/Line_Group_Features.gif" /></td></tr></table>
    </font></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" vAlign="top">
    <img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/192/images/clear1x1.gif" width="1" height="4" border="0"><br />
    </td><td></td><td>
    <SELECT name="SELECT___S15FTAN01___29" onChange="change_option('SELECT___S15FTAN01___29',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <OPTION value="176" >Ivory/Grey</OPTION>
    </SELECT>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" vAlign="top">
    <img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/192/images/clear1x1.gif" width="1" height="4" border="0"><br />
    </td><td></td><td>
    <SELECT name="SELECT___S15FTAN01___31" onChange="change_option('SELECT___S15FTAN01___31',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <OPTION value="167" >0/3 months</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="169" >3/6 months</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="175" >6/9 months</OPTION>
    </SELECT>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: It is always recommended  to use some html parsers. Regex is not the right tool for matching html tags

Comment: I know Regular Expression is not right track to do this parsing job but it is recommended from my side.

Comment: Depending on which programming language you use, you may have to use double backslashes like in PHP. Because the backslash needs to be escaped itself, otherwise you would for example just escape the `s`.

Comment: @syck Thanks for your comment.. I am using these in GoLang.Can you please help to parse this .? Can you please look at this what should be the Regex ?

Comment: Consult the documentation of the language you use for details about string (and regex) representation. For working out the regexes, you could use some online regex tester like regex101, but at a first glance, they look fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, GoLang, but I can tell you in perl, and I think you will be able to relate to GoLang.

Firstly, regex to store `table tag` content (https://regex101.com/r/tL7dA0/1):

```
$table = $1 if ($html =~ m/<table.*?>(.*)<\/table>/igs);
```

Regex for printing all the things between `select` tag (https://regex101.com/r/xJ0xU1/1):

```
 while ($table =~ m/<select.*?>(.*?)<\/select>/isg){
            print $1."\n";
        }
```

As in your case, if html table contains inner table, then all the content of outer table would be selected.

```
i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```